# extending PAC bound result to validation set generalization error

Tags: pac-learning

I PAC-bound I learned consider the following decompistion:

$R(f) = R_n(f) + \left(R(f) - R_n(f)\right)$

where $R(f)$ is the test error, $R_n(f)$ is the training error $\left(R(f) - R_n(f)\right)$ is defined as generalization error. However in practice, we often talk about test/validation error with a slightly different definition, where the error is w.r.t. a validation/test set where training data is not included. I wonder in this case how to derive the corresponding generalization error.